Create and Run Task When Installing/Uninstalling Compose Desktop App
I am working on a Compose Desktop App and wonder how do I run some tasks like create a shortcut in Window Start Menu Folder after the installation, and delete some files when uninstalling.
Or is there a tool that allows more customizations for installation/uninstallation?
